# JQuery wait for Ajax Result

Tags: jquery

I have a function making Asp.Net Web service calls by taking method name and data as parameters. There is no problem sending data to service. But my retun value is `undefined`

```
function ServiceCommand(method, mdata) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Service1.asmx/" + method,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: mdata,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (msg) {
                    return msg;
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    return "error";
                }
            });
        }

function Insert()
{
var Msg = ServiceCommand("HelloWorld", "{pwd:'1234',txt:'SomeText'}");
alert(Msg);// undefined

}
```

How can I make ServiceCommand function wait until a response comes? I'm using JQuery 1.9 (`async:false` doesn't work)
I saw some solutions advising usage of `$.When` but I couln't figure out how to use here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: No, that answer suggests async: false which can't be used here.

Comment: Then you haven't read the answer properly. I actually explicitly say **not** to use `async: false`. Or how would you interpret *"1. Synchronous AJAX calls -- DON'T DO IT*"?

Comment: Any reason you need to return a value? Can you not just perform the necessary operation in the success function?

Comment: @FelixKling is right - the answer explains passing in a callback function that can be set for the success function.

Comment: @FelixKling You are right. But the document was too complex for a JQuery beginner so I couldn't apply the solutions on my case.

Comment: Have a look at the *Let functions accept callbacks* part which is exactly what rhoadsce used in his answer. Hopefully you can recognize the similarities. Callbacks have nothing in particular to do with jQuery btw, they are just a common JavaScript technique. If you find the answer to complicated, I'm always happy about suggestions how to simplify the description/code.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your interest but I couldn't success using .when

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this without using promises (.when) would be to pass a callback function into ServiceCommand as a third parameter. This function would do whatever it is that you need to do with the response from the ajax call.

```
function ServiceCommand(method, mdata, onSuccessCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Service1.asmx/" + method,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: mdata,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (onSuccessCallback !== undefined) {
                    onSuccessCallback(msg);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                return "error";
            }
        });
    }

function Insert()
{
    var Msg = ServiceCommand("HelloWorld", "{pwd:'1234',txt:'SomeText'}", onSuccess);
    alert(Msg);
}
function onSuccess(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Can you also show the option using .when()

Comment: @aliassce: You only need `$.when` if you work with multiple Ajax calls / promises. I suggest again that you have a look at the answer I linked to, it tries to explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

use  async=false;

```
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl,
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false
```